# Styling the disabled option in react-select

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I want to style the text (italic etc) of a disabled option within a `react-select`. Though this seems pretty basic to me, I can't find anything about it.

Is there an own 'style key' for a disabled option?

Comment: isDisabled={this.props.disabled}

Comment: Please Share your code for better understanding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `react-select`'s [styles API](https://react-select.com/styles)

Here is an example:

```js
const customStyles = {
  // For the select itself (not the options)
  control: (styles, { isDisabled }) => {
    return {
      ...styles,
      color: isDisabled ? 'red' : 'white'
      fontStyle: isDisabled ? "italic" : "normal";
    }
  },
  // For the options
  option: (styles, { isDisabled }) => {
    const color = chroma(data.color);
    return {
      ...styles,
      backgroundColor: isDisabled ? 'red' : 'blue',
      color: 'green',
    };
  },
};
```

Then use it like this:

```js
 <Select
    {...props}
    styles={customStyles}
  />
```

Comment: Jeeez, I went thru the Styles API several times but couldn't find this here ... thank you!